# Forcing pip to look at a locally installed package instead of a globally installed package

Tags: pip

I'm using pip to install a software package with multiple dependencies onto a linux environment. Everything runs smooth when I call the `pip install <package>` up until the very end, when I get the error that a globally installed dependency package is out of date, meaning I should update the global version. Due to reasons beyond my control, doing this is out of the question. So, I installed an updated version to `~/bin`. How do I tell pip to look there for the updated version?

Comment: I am not sure this qualifies as an SO question, nevertheless if you install the updated package to the user installation (using the flag `--user`) and then retry installing the target module as a user as well everything should go according to the plan.

Comment: What OS you are using?